# Why adding role in laravel-permission I got invalid table table name error?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 9 / spatie/laravel-permission 5.5 I add new role with :

```
$role = Role::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'guard_name' => 'web',
]);
```

and I got error :
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'BiCurrencies.roles' doesn't exist

In config/permission.php I have option :

```
'table_names' => [
    'roles' => 'spt_roles',
    ...
```

and I Models/Role.php I set :

```
class Role extends Model implements RoleContract
{
    use HasPermissions;
    use RefreshesPermissionCache;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'spt_roles';
```

Why error and how my config options must be applied ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I set custom models I had to set them in file config/permission.php

```
return [
    'models' => [
        'permission' => App\Models\Permission::class,
        'role' => App\Models\Role::class,
    ],
```

it works for me.